SLD styling a polygon with a base fill and a transparent pattern png
With geoserver 2.25, I am trying to add a graphic fill overlaid on a base color with an external graphic. Here is my code but it is not working.
     <Rule>
      <Name>Qafy</Name>
      <Description>
        <Title>Qafy</Title>
      </Description>
      <Filter>
        <PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <PropertyName>unit_symbol</PropertyName>
          <Literal>Qafy</Literal>
        </PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </Filter>

      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <SvgParameter name="fill">#ffffb2</SvgParameter>
          <SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</SvgParameter>
        </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>

      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <GraphicFill>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="0cdc9a0f-0ca9-49ec-bfc8-a7bd8967843e.png"/>
                <Format>image/png</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Opacity>0.5</Opacity>
              <Size>18.3375</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </GraphicFill>
        </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>


what is not working? please provide a picture of the output and a description of what you were expecting to see

So when the graphic points to web server that hosts the png it doesn't work. (I realize the full web address is not in the code above) If I upload the png within the web admin ui under styles, it works. Also note that since it is a transparent background png, I changed the opacity to 1 and the symbology works as intended.

Did you authorize the URL in the security settings?
